# How do I find a certain Child image in a Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a Canvas that has 400 children. Each of the children is a rectangle and is filled with an Image. If I want to find a certain image, how would I go doing about that?

```
//My code to fill a rectangle
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"hero.png", UriKind.Relative));
img.Margin = rec.Margin;
ImageBrush imgbrush = new ImageBrush();
imgbrush.ImageSource = img.Source;
rec.Fill = imgbrush;

//My attempt at finding that certain rectangle
 foreach (Rectangle rec in canvas1.Children)
        {
            if (rec.Fill = ImageBrush.ImageSourceProperty) // I tried to compare the rectangle with the image's source
            {

            }                
        }
```

Comment: just give your images some names by using img.Name = ... , then you can use it for retrieving a specific one.

Comment: What is the Image control good for? It is never added to any container. Why not directly assign `imgbrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(...)`?

Comment: What do you want the image for? I'm sensing some lack of MVVM here. Even if it's a game, MVVM can simplify things a lot. I have done Tile-based MVVM games myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use names for for every specific `Image` then using [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) Method

```
object wantedNode = stackPanel.FindName("dog");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the objects in an array (key/pair) that you can later iterate through?